# URL query change from plus to minus

Tags: php, url, query-string

How can i change plus to minus from url query for example:
from
?search=some+words
to
?search=some-words 
Because if i use + i get results only from the first word.
Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: It depends where do you want to make the change: PHP/htaccess...

Comment: i found out $search = rawurlencode(strip_tags(str_replace("_", " ", $_GET['search'])));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$search = rawurlencode(strip_tags(str_replace("_", " ", $_GET['search'])));

Answer (score 0):

Excellent overview about the different possibilites including examples [here](http://www.rither.de/a/informatik/php-beispiele/strings/urls-encodieren-und-decodieren/).

It's in german, but the code is self-explaining.

```
<?php

$_GET['parameter1'] = urlencode('Dies ist ein längerer Beispielstring');
var_dump($_GET['parameter1']);
var_dump(urldecode($_GET['parameter1']));

$_GET['parameter2'] = rawurlencode('Dies ist ein längerer Beispielstring');
var_dump($_GET['parameter2']);
var_dump(rawurldecode($_GET['parameter2']));

// urlencode() macht aus dem Leerzeichen ein +
// rawurlencode() hingegen ein %20
var_dump(urlencode(' '), urldecode(urlencode(' ')));
var_dump(rawurlencode(' '), rawurldecode(rawurlencode(' ')));

var_dump(urlencode('+'), urldecode(urlencode('+')));
var_dump(rawurlencode('+'), rawurldecode(rawurlencode('+')));
```

results in

```
string(41) "Dies+ist+ein+l%C3%A4ngerer+Beispielstring"
string(37) "Dies ist ein längerer Beispielstring"
string(49) "Dies%20ist%20ein%20l%C3%A4ngerer%20Beispielstring"
string(37) "Dies ist ein längerer Beispielstring"
string(1) "+"
string(1) " "
string(3) "%20"
string(1) " "
string(3) "%2B"
string(1) "+"
string(3) "%2B"
string(1) "+"
```

**I would like to add that Apache's configs and mod_rewrite can affect this behaviour.**